# how to use where function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to inject to NoSql database.

I have search all over the web trying to understand what to do in order to inject to a simple form written in HTML and a server side in node.js.
so usually when I need to get data out of the database that is in mLab I just use the query mycollection.find({name: req.body.name}) but as I understood (please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm not the sure about it) I need to use where function because it is easy to inject by using this function to my DB.

this is what I did

```
exports.getDetails = function(req, res){
    var myuser = req.body.user;
    login.findOne({ $where : {name: myuser} }, function(err, docs){
        console.log(docs);
    });
}
```

but the function where does not work.. what did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'trying to inject'? From your code, it seems like what you're really trying to do is get details of a particular user.

Comment: later on I want to use my input tag to inject a query to this function in order to get the DB (later).
I need to inject it later on with the user name lets say it's lala and then a function so it will be like
lala', function(){ res.json('I can insert thins');}'
this is form what I read not sure how it will work yet..

this function does not work for me for even getting one user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following snippet. This will work.

```
exports.getDetails = function(req, res){
    var myuser = req.body.user;
    login.find({ $where : {name: myuser}}).toArray(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
}
```

Comment: TypeError: login.find(...).toArray is not a function

I get this error messege

Answer (score 0):

From the official Mongo documentation for [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

> Use the $where operator to pass either a string containing a JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query system. The $where provides greater flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection. Reference the document in the JavaScript expression or function using either this or obj .

In your code you are sending an object which is wrong(you can only send Javascript expression as a string or a function). I don`t think you need $where based on your example. Just do this if you want to get one user :

```
login.findOne({name: 'enterNameHere'},function(err, user){
     console.log(user);
});
```

You can find examples for $where in the documentation **(bottom of the page)**